# I want to examine df_entry_log['AM_PM'] and, dependant on a test populate a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

this is driving me insane. I am using

```
3.10.13 (main, Aug 25 2023, 13:20:03) [GCC 9.4.0]
pandas version 2.1.1
numpy version 1.26.2
pyarrow version 14.0.1
```

I want to examine `df_entry_log['AM_PM']` and, dependant on a test populate a column.

create a column `df_entry_log['bag_weight']`

if `df_entry_log['AM_PM'] = "AM"` then look up `df_details['bag_weight']` using `df_entry_log['prev_wrk_day']` and put the value in  `df_entry_log['bag_weight']` ie `97.10`

else `df_entry_log['AM_PM'] == "PM'` put the value of `df_details['bag_weight']` found looking up `df_entry_log['entry_date']`

I wanted to use a vector BUT my mind has gone to mush.

df_entry_log:

```
      guest     entry_date     AM_PM  prev_wrk_day   next_wrk_day
1     janet     2007-01-17     PM     2007-01-16     2007-01-18
2     janet     2007-04-25     AM     2007-04-24     2007-04-26
3     janet     2007-07-25     AM     2007-07-24     2007-07-26
```

df_details

```
      guest    gate_date  bag_weight
8     janet     2007-01-16     97.10    
9     janet     2007-01-17     94.95   
10    janet     2007-01-18     89.07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
def get_weight(row):
    try:
        if row["AM_PM"] == "AM":
            return df_details.loc[(row["guest"], row["prev_wrk_day"]), "bag_weight"]
        else:
            return df_details.loc[(row["guest"], row["entry_date"]), "bag_weight"]
    except KeyError:
        return np.nan

# set index to guest/gate_date for easy searching:
df_details = df_details.set_index(["guest", "gate_date"])
df_entry_log["bag_weight"] = df_entry_log.apply(get_weight, axis=1)

print(df_entry_log)
```

Prints:

```
   guest  entry_date AM_PM prev_wrk_day next_wrk_day  bag_weight
1  janet  2007-01-17    PM   2007-01-16   2007-01-18       94.95
2  janet  2007-04-25    AM   2007-04-24   2007-04-26         NaN
3  janet  2007-07-25    AM   2007-07-24   2007-07-26         NaN
```

Comment: thank you Andrej for breaking the brainfreeze. What you coded worked excellently and I thank you for that. In the end I looked at your approach and modified it a little. Thank yo for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Andrej's answer was excellent and worked well. He helped me out. In the end I decided to take this approach

```
def get_impliedEarningsMove_vectorized(row, df_summaries):
    try:
        mask_am = row["AM_PM"] == "AM"
        mask_pm = ~mask_am

        am_condition = (df_summaries["ticker"] == row["ticker"]) & (df_summaries["tradeDate"] == row["prev_wrk_day"])
        pm_condition = (df_summaries["ticker"] == row["ticker"]) & (df_summaries["tradeDate"] == row["ernDate1"])

        result_am = df_summaries.loc[am_condition, "impliedEarningsMove"].values if mask_am else np.array([np.nan])
        result_pm = df_summaries.loc[pm_condition, "impliedEarningsMove"].values if mask_pm else np.array([np.nan])

        return np.where(mask_am, result_am, result_pm)[0]
    except IndexError:
        return np.nan
```